# Kendo grid filter is not working on the Id column

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I've created a kendo grid and everything is going well but unfortunately  the filter on the Id column is not working at all even it doesn't return error or exception and i don't know whats wrong
you can find my grid below:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: url,
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                try {
                    var result = {
                        take: options.take,
                        skip: options.skip
                    };

                    if (options.sort) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < options.sort.length; i++) {
                            result["sort[" + i + "].field"] = options.sort[i].field;
                            result["sort[" + i + "].dir"] = options.sort[i].dir;
                        }
                    }


                    if (options.filter != "" && options.filter != undefined) {
                        if ('filter' in options && options.filter.filters.length > 0) {
                            result["filter"] = options.filter;
                        }
                    }


                    return result;

                } catch (e) {
                    alert("error:" + e);
                }
            },
        },
        schema: {
            total: function (data) {
                return data.Total;

            },
            data: function (data) {
                return data.Data;
            },
            model: {
                //Id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number" },
                    //ComplainDateTime: { type: "date", format: "{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss}" },
                    ComplainDateTime: { type: "string" },
                    DetailDescription: { type: "string" },
                    ComplainSourceName: { type: "string" },
                    UserId: { type: "string" },
                    StatusName: { type: "string" },
                    ComplainTypeName: { type: "string" },
                    ZoneName: { type: "string" },
                    StatusId: { type: "number" }
                }
            }
        },
        type: "json",
        pageSize: 10,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true
    });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        filterable: {
            extra: false
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        resizable: true,
        width: '100%',
        dataBound: onDataBound,
        columns: [
            {
                field: "Id",
                title: '@ComplainRes.ComplainNumber',
                width: "10%",
                filterable: { extra: true },

            },
            {
                field: "ComplainDateTime",
                title: '@ComplainRes.ComplainDate',

                filterable: { extra: true },
                width: "13%"
            },
            {
                field: "DetailDescription",
                title: '@ComplainRes.ComplainDesc',
                width: "15%"
            },
            {
                field: "ComplainSourceName",
                title: '@ComplainRes.ComplainSource',
                width: "10%"
            },
            {
                field: "UserId",
                title: '@ComplainRes.ComplainSupervisor',
                width: "10%"
            },
            {
                field: "StatusName",
                title: '@ComplainRes.ComplainStatus',
                width: "10%"
            }, {
                field: "ComplainTypeName",
                title: '@ComplainRes.ComplainType',
                width: "12%"

            },
            {
                field: "ZoneName",
                title: '@ComplainRes.Zone',
                width: "10%",
                filterable: {
                    ui: ZonesFilter
                }
            },
            {
                hidden: true,
                field: "StatusId",
                filterable: false,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                filterable: false,
                sortable: false,
                width: "6%",
                field: "Id",
                template: "<div class='text-center'><a  style='color: \\#029b5b!important' href='javascript:getDetails(#: Id #)'><i class='fa fa-file-text-o fa-fw fa-2x'></i></a></div>",
                title: '@CommonRes.Details'
            },
            {
                filterable: false,
                sortable: false,
                width: "6%",
                field: "Id",
                template: "<div class='text-center'><a  style='color: \\#029b5b!important' href='javascript:getHistory(#: Id #)'><img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/new/HistoryICon.png")'/></a></div>",
                title: '@ComplainRes.ComplainHistorytit'
            }
        ]
    });

    $('.k-grid-filter').click(function () {
        $('.k-animation-container').addClass('k-rtl');
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the result of the Id column being a number.. Kendo tries to apply a 'tolowercase()' method on the value and since it's a number it throws an error. Your best (and easiest) option is to just convert it to a string before you assign the view model to kendo...otherwise you have to do some schema manipulation on the datasource itself.